# Structure Constants Lie Algebra Quaternions

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, quaternions

I am a little bit confused by this (Taken by the MIT thesis Of M. Johnson). The first question is why is there the sum of the structure constants?  I mean, in $R^3$ it is enough the scalar product between two basis to get the third, isn't it?

The second thing is that I don't understand why the $C_{ijk}$ is defined in terms of permutations of $(1,2,3)$. As I was mentioning, I would say that:

$E_i \times E_j = E_k$

and:

$E_j \times E_i = -E_k$

And I don't see how the sum of the structure constants are related to it. 
Last thing, correct me if I am wrong, a permutation is cyclic if it is the result of an even number of transposition, it is anti-cyclic if it is the result of an odd number of transposition, when it says "otherwise" then, is it referring to the indentity permutation?

Thanks!

[image: ern]

Comment: You talk about the "sum of the structure constants", but the quoted text never mentions such a sum. Also you say $E_i\times E_j=E_k$. Is that true for $(i,j,k)=(3,2,1)$ or $(i,j,k)=(2,1,2)$ etc.?

Comment: When I say "sum" I mean the term $\sum{C_{ijk}}$. As for the other question, what do you mean by $(i,j,k)=(3,2,1)$ etc? I think I am missing something obvious. Aren't the structure constants $i*j=k$, $i*k=j$, $j*k=i$? If so, what is the permutation referring to?

Comment: There is no sum $\sum C_{ijk}$. The sum in the quoted text is $\sum_k C_{ijk}e_k$.

Comment: So the permutations are referred to the order in which i, j and k appears? and by cyclic it means when all of them get permuted and anti cyclic when only 2 of them commute (hence why the minus gets introduced). But still, in which case the permutation yields to 0? and the sum $\sum{C_{ijk},E_k}$, what is summing exactly? I mean, it multiplies the product $i*j*k$ by the basis $e_k$, according to a certain permutation of the basis, and I don't see what gets summed together. If you have time to write a little explanation I will be happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you just lack familiarity with the notation. Let's write out the formula $[E_i, E_j] = \sum_k C_{ijk} E_k$ which seems to confuse you, for the instances $ (1,1), (1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ for $(i,j)$:

$$[E_1, E_1] = \underbrace{C_{111}}_{0} E_1 + \underbrace{C_{112}}_0 E_2 + \underbrace{C_{113}}_0 E_3 = 0$$

$$[E_1, E_2] = \underbrace{C_{121}}_{0} E_1 + \underbrace{C_{122}}_0 E_2 + \underbrace{C_{123}}_1 E_3 = E_3$$

$$[E_2, E_1] = \underbrace{C_{211}}_{0} E_1 + \underbrace{C_{212}}_0 E_2 + \underbrace{C_{213}}_{-1} E_3 = -E_3$$

etc. Surely you can fill in the other possibilities for $(i,j)$ and see how this is just a different notation for what you wrote.